# Grab image from input field to get image data / display image

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file-upload, onchange

I've been looking around and haven't been able to find whether this is possible or not.

This is what I would like to happen before submitted: When a user selects a file to be uploaded, I want to grab the image's data and convert it to base64.  After it's been converted, I would like to either directly display it in a `div` or have it sent to the server via AJAX, then displayed in the `div`.

Below is basically what I'm looking for:

```
// index.php
<input type="file" name="img" id="img" onChange="displayImg(this)">

// displayImg.js
function displayImg(img) {
   imgData = img.?;  // How do I do this?
   img64 =           // I know how to do this.
   document.write("<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,"+img64+"' />");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function displayImage(evt){
  var files = evt.target.files;
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(frEvent) {
      document.getElementById("renderImage").innerHTML = '<img src="'+frEvent.target.result+'" />';
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
```

The code above works for me.  It lacks verification and all that good stuff, but this should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: "Works" in which browsers? How likely is it to continue "working" in the future?

Comment: I've tested my version of this code and it works in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.  It doesn't work in IE, and Safari returns an error of "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FileReader"

Comment: I needed to change "reader.onload(function(theFile){" to "reader.onload=(function(theFile){" for it to work